# Error trying to save scraped web data to a text file

Tags: python, selenium, twitter, file-writing

I am new, and recently started using Python. I am trying to save the retrieved Twitter followers from web to a text file but it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
for twusernames in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@aria-label="Timeline: Followers"]//a[@role="link"]'):
    print(twusernames.get_property('href'))
    file = open('links.txt', 'w')
    file.write(twusernames.get_property('href'))
    file.close()
```

What am I doing wrong? :( Thanks for help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In this case, it would help to explain what exactly isn't working (error messages, etc.)

Comment: Thank you. I will!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```py
with open('links.txt', 'w') as file
for twusernames in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@aria-label="Timeline: Followers"]//a[@role="link"]'):
    content = twusernames.get_property('href')
    print(content)
    file.write(content)
file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.

Comment: If so please accept my answer.

Comment: Done. All of three have been helpful and tough to select one, haha. I wish I could upvote. :)

Comment: Thanks for choosing me  I have upvoted you back, so it will bring you faster to be able to upvote as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
with open('links.txt', 'w') as file
    file.write(twusernames.get_property('href'))
    file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you. I got my solution.

Answer (score 0):

### get_attribute()

[get_attribute()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) gets the given attribute or property of the element. This method first tries to return the value of a property with the given name. If a property with that name doesn’t exist, it returns the value of the attribute with the same name. If there is no attribute with that name, `None` is returned. Values which are considered truthy, that is equals "true" or "false", are returned as booleans. All other non-`None` values are returned as strings. For attributes or properties which do not exist, `None` is returned. To obtain the exact value of the attribute or property you can also use [get_dom_attribute()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_dom_attribute) or [get_property()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_property) methods.

Additionally, once you open a `file_handle` you need to close it. However, file operations being I/O operations must be as less as possible. So effectively your optimized code block will be:

- Using *`get_attribute()`*:

  ```
  file = open("links.txt", "w")
  for twusernames in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@aria-label="Timeline: Followers"]//a[@role="link"]'):
      file.write(twusernames.get_attribute("href") + "\n")
  file.close()
  ```
- Using *`get_property()`*:

  ```
  file = open("links.txt", "w")
  for twusernames in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@aria-label="Timeline: Followers"]//a[@role="link"]'):
      file.write(twusernames.get_property("href") + "\n")
  file.close()
  ```
- Using *`get_dom_attribute()`*:

  ```
  file = open("links.txt", "w")
  for twusernames in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@aria-label="Timeline: Followers"]//a[@role="link"]'):
      file.write(twusernames.get_dom_attribute("href") + "\n")
  file.close()
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. This helped me understand to look at it from different ways.